# dynamically changing array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

is it possible somehow change array which is processed by foreach? I tried this script

```
$iterator = 10;
$cat = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b',3 => 'c');

foreach ($cat as $k => $c)
{
    if ($iterator < 15)
    {
        $cat[$iterator] = $iterator;
        $iterator++;
    }
    echo $c;  
}
```

but it isn't changing the 'foreached' array. The output from foreach is

> abc

but var_dump from array after foreach is

> array(6) { [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c" [10]=> int(10) [11]=> int(11) [12]=> int(12) }

That means 10,11,12 were added in foreach cyclus, but foreach didn't iterate over them? Is it possible to do that? Or do I need to make 2foreach cyclus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$iterator = 10;
$cat = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b',3 => 'c');

foreach ($cat as $k => &$c)//observe the '&'
{
    if ($iterator < 15)
    {
        $cat[$iterator] = $iterator;
        $iterator++;
    }
    echo $c;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The internet needs more cats! pass the array by reference instead and you'll get the desired result.  note the `&$cat` in the loop.

```
$iterator = 10;
$cat = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b',3 => 'c');

foreach($cat as $k => &$c)
{
    if ($iterator < 15)
    {
        $cat[$iterator] = $iterator;
        $iterator++;
    }
    echo $c;  
}
```

Comment: ha, true I noticed that after i pushed post. so eager to get the points.

Comment: amended. I stand by my previous statement about the cats

Comment: cat is short to category, not the animal...but yes, we need more cats and dogs...not fuus and bars :D

Comment: @adamS +1 to your efforts also

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you *should not*. Because `foreach` will work with copy of array. That means - it will firstly copy your array and then loop through it. And no matter if you'll change original array - since you're working with it's copy inside `foreach`, any modification will affect only *original* array and not looped copy.

But - yes, after `foreach` you will see your changes in *original* array. Besides, there is little sense in doing such thing. It's hard to read and may case unpredictable results.

One important thing that wasn't mentioned. The following wont work:

```
$iterator = 10;
$cat = array(1 => 'a');//only one element; same for empty array

foreach ($cat as $k => &$c)
{
    if ($iterator < 15)
    {
        $cat[$iterator] = $iterator;
        $iterator++;
    }
    echo $c;
}
```

-because of how PHP deals with array pointer in `foreach`.

Comment: I don't understand it, but the upper solution works...so I accepted it I right answer. Anyway, I make my solution with 2 foreach, i found out that even in one foreach I have to check and how you said, it make all hard to read. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. the point is - no sense in changing _original_ array as it is. Either work with reference or be prepared that changes will be seen only after loop